# How to write a MVVM with Windsor and ViewModel first approch

Tags: wpf, mvvm, castle-windsor

Is there any sample code that uses Windsor for a WPF application? I am interested to see how the Mainwindow is created when the selected approach is ViewModel first? I cannot get it to work as when VM is created first, I don't have access to View so I cannot add it to main window(The view is created by Windsor and hence I don’t have access to it, I only have access to IView which is not a window, or control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a sample for Silverlight on windsor wiki
http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Silvertlight_Sample_App_Customer_contact_manager.ashx

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination of marker interfaces, custom activators and a custom facility to wire up my WPF views, view models and dependencies in Windsor.  I wrote about it in a [column for Visual Studio Magazine](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/10/01/wpf-and-inversion-of-control.aspx).  It may help you out.